# Xhtml.of_string_unsafe disable onclick

Tags: opa

I have a problem, here is a short example :

```
Xhtml.of_string_unsafe(Xhtml.to_string(<button onclick={_->jlog("coucou")}>bouton</button>))
```

And when i click on the button, nothing happen...

Is there a bug in opa ?

Comment: Hmmm, looks like a bug to me. I'll make a JIRA entry. Will keep you posted.

Answer (score 2):

First element of answer: to speed-up loading of pages, Opa loads puts first the HTML and defers the script tags (loading all the client side code) until the end of the page. In the normal use case, onclick actions are then delegated until after the loading of the JS code. This cannot happen here, and your example in fact shows a JS error: it tries to use jQuery, which is not loaded yet (it is loaded as part of the all.js file).

Instead, if you insert this unsafe XHTML dynamically, so after the JS has been loaded, then you don't get an error. The example code is:

```
page() = 
  btn = Xhtml.of_string_unsafe(Xhtml.to_string(<button onclick={_ ->jlog("coucou")}>bouton</button>))
  <span id="toto" onready={_ -> Dom.transform([#toto <- btn])} />
server = one_page_server("Test", page)
```

However, it still does not work. I have no idea why yet.

Comment: Right, the dynamic version is very unlikely to work properly, because we insert in the DOM a new <script> tag (worse, a sanitized version of it to avoid potential XSS), and these don't seem to get interpreted by web browsers. We should instead call directly the JS functions, rather than inserting the script tag, and that's exactly what's done in the normal case (i.e. without going through Xhtml.of_string_unsafe). As a conclusion, yes it indeed does not work, but it cannot be repaired easily. Xhtml.of_string_unsafe is really a convenience hack, but a very limited one.

Comment: By the way, what were you trying to use it for ? Maybe there's a better way.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is "normal", transforming an XHTML into a basic string can't keep the event handlers...

The onclick is not serialized into the string.

Can somebody confirm?

Comment: I think the transformation does (should) keep the event handlers (as JS). You can confirm that by printing the string obtained from `Xhtml.to_string`